# startElement in SAXParser can not be recognised

Tags: java, xml, dom, saxparser

i am learning how to parse xml data using SAX builder, and i am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/), the problem is when i implemented the `startElement` method shown below, eclipse underscores the `Attributes` parameter in red and says `Attributes cannot be resolved to a type`

please let me know how to fix it

**code**:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
                bfname = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
                blname = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NICKNAME")) {
                bnname = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SALARY")) {
                bsalary = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: which version have you using? signature seems to be ok for [Java7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes))

Comment: @JordiCastilla it is java 8 build 1.8.0

Comment: @JordiCastilla i found it. i should have imported import org.xml.sax.Attributes;   should i turn my comment to an answer or not

Comment: Glad to hear you solved! ;) about answer... As you prefer, you can auto answer if you think it will be useful or dete question... Up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i should have imported the following:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

add following import:

`import org.xml.sax.Attributes;`